# How can I configure openshift to find the my RabbitMQ definitions.json?

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift

I am experiencing this problem or a similiar problem:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2374351 (RabbitMQ users and its permission are deleted after resource restart)

But the proposed fix is not public.

I would like to have a user name & password hash pair which can survive a complete crash.

I am not sure how with openshift templates to programmatically upload or define definitions.json. I can upload the definitions.json to here /var/lib/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json with winscp.

If my definitions.json is uploaded from hand, after a crash the user names and hashes get reloaded. However I don't want to upload from hand. I would like to configure openshift and save that configuration.

My only idea is to trying to access one openshift ConfigMap from another.

I have two config maps:

```
plattform-rabbitmq-configmap
definitions.json
```

I want the ConfigMap **plattform-rabbitmq-configmap** to reference the ConfigMap **definitions.json**.

**plattform-rabbitmq-configmap** contains my rabbitmq.config. In plattform-rabbitmq-configmap I want to access or load definitions.json.

Using the oc get configmaps command I got a selflink for definitions.json. Using the selflink I try to load the definitions.json as follows (in plattform-rabbitmq-configmap):

```
load_definitions,"/api/v1/namespaces/my-app/configmaps/definitions.json"}
```

But that doesn't work:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Mar-2018::15:08:40 ===
application: rabbit
exited: {bad_return,
            {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
             {'EXIT',
                 {error,
                     {could_not_read_defs,
                         {"/api/v1/namespaces/my-app/configmaps/definitions.json",
                          enoent}}}}}}
type: transient
```

Is there any way to do this? Or another way?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You are trying to get help on a solution for something, but if you explain the original problem maybe can suggest way of doing it. That ``selfLink`` is not going to be of any use as it relates to the REST API and not file system path access.

Comment: What path in the container did you mount the config maps? Knowing that, you just need to know the filesystem path to where ``definitions.json`` was mounted and use it. So what mount point did you use when mounting config map from command line using ``oc set volume``, or when using web console to mount the config map via the deployment config?

Comment: I used the ui to create the config maps, so I am not sure where they are actually are. Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: Go to the deployment config in the web console. You should see a Volumes section which mentions the config map. Then under Containers you should see something like: ``Mount: config → /opt/app-root/configs read-write``, where ``config`` is the name of the config map. The path is the mount point. It should be visible inside of that directory container as a file. You would have specified that path when you mounted, so presumably you would know it.

Comment: Lovely, it seems like I just need to add the definitions.json using "Add Config Files", and then I should be able to point to it.  plattform-rabbitmq-configmap was mounted for me using the rabbitmq template so I wasn't sure where it was.

Comment: Odd it didn't work. My mounts are                                                   
Mount: config-volume → /var/configs read-only (for rabbitmq.config)
Mount: volume-8t1b9 → /var/configs/users (for definitions.json)  when I go into the /var/configs the rabbitmq.config is there, but /var/configs/users is empty

Comment: Be careful where you mount it. Use a directory which doesn't exist. Don't try and mount on directory which has other files already in it. Also be careful about mounting on same directory, or as subdirectory, to where other config maps may be mounted, as there may be some issues with doing that.

Comment: Sorry, don't ever use StackOverflow chat. There is an OpenShift mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift